# How can I add multiple elements of pairs in a multimap c++ using the insert()

Tags: c++, insert, containers, maps, element

```
std::multimap<std::string, int> student;
student.insert({"John", 78}, {"Adam", 98});
```

what syntax am I missing here or is it not possible to do and only a single pair element can be inserted at one time.  I am aware that multisets can insert multiples values at a time like so,

```
std::multiset<int> grades;
grades.insert({87, 78, 66});
```

Please let me know what if there is any way to do this?

Comment: `void insert( std::initializer_list<value_type> ilist );`. Is this the overload you are trying to call? If yes, then try `student.insert({{"John", 78}, {"Adam", 98}});`

Answer (score 0):

Oh silly me! I forgot to include the parenthesis in my original code since I was using two strings as key and value.  So yeah! It can be done. The above code would actually work with added pair of curly braces.

```
student.insert({{"John", 78}, {"Adam", 98}});
```

Comment: yes, the insert braces like insert().  It was a long line so i missed it

Comment: What I meant was the normal parenthesis which you put the element to insert. I missed to put those because i was using a lot of curly braces to put the key value pairs

Comment: it should be, `student.insert({{"John", 78}, {"Adam", 98}});`